# FFMPEG concat filter has unconnected audio output

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to concat an arbitrary video file with a video file of 5 seconds of black. Here is the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i tmp/converted_one_1234.mp4 -i public/empty.mp4 -vsync 2 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1024:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1024:576:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[v0]; [1:v]scale=1024:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1024:576:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[v1]; [v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map [v] -map [a] output.mp4
```

And the error:

```
Filter concat:out:a0 has an unconnected output
```

So I understand the issue is that there is an audio stream that is not getting mapped to an output. The arbitrary video has audio in it, the black video technically has no sound, but it has an audio stream (verified with ffprobe).

I think I'm just missing how the syntax works here. I've tried removing the audio input from this section:

```
[v0][0:a][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]
```

but it doesn't work. How do I avoid this error?

edit with complete log of ffmpeg events (i should note that before this failing operation, there is one in which the arbitrary video gets converted to an mp4. The concat fails regardless of whether the first conversion is included):

```
    ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/27173/custom_video/final/IMG_2753.mp4?1625616358':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 00:00:15.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 802 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 320x568, 723 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 70 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
File 'tmp/converted_one_27173.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp2 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7fe770820400] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7fe770820400] profile High, level 3.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7fe770820400] 264 - core 163 r3060 5db6aa6 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'tmp/converted_one_27173.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 320x568, q=2-31, 30 fps, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp2 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 384 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 mp2
frame=  478 fps=353 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2033kB time=00:00:15.89 bitrate=1047.8kbits/s speed=11.7x    
video:1271kB audio:747kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.769286%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe770820400] frame I:11    Avg QP:23.67  size:  9018
[libx264 @ 0x7fe770820400] frame P:200   Avg QP:25.18  size:  4565
[libx264 @ 0x7fe770820400] frame B:267   Avg QP:30.02  size:  1081
[libx264 @ 0x7fe770820400] consecutive B-frames: 20.5% 12.1%  8.8% 58.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe770820400] mb I  I16..4:  9.3% 78.4% 12.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe770820400] mb P  I16..4: 10.3% 32.2%  1.0%  P16..4: 34.0% 12.3%  5.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 5.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe770820400] mb B  I16..4:  1.0%  4.2%  0.1%  B16..8: 50.8%  4.2%  0.3%  direct: 1.7%  skip:37.6%  L0:52.8% L1:42.8% BI: 4.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe770820400] 8x8 transform intra:75.0% inter:70.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe770820400] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 47.7% 64.1% 8.5% inter: 17.0% 19.6% 2.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe770820400] i16 v,h,dc,p: 17% 21%  8% 53%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe770820400] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 23% 15%  5%  7%  7%  7%  5%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe770820400] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 24% 14%  5%  9%  7%  9%  5%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe770820400] i8c dc,h,v,p: 47% 25% 20%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe770820400] Weighted P-Frames: Y:11.5% UV:5.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe770820400] ref P L0: 73.5% 12.0% 11.9%  2.0%  0.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe770820400] ref B L0: 96.0%  3.8%  0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe770820400] ref B L1: 98.1%  1.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe770820400] kb/s:653.11
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Trailing option(s) found in the command: may be ignored.
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'tmp/converted_one_27173.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 00:00:15.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1045 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 320x568, 653 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 384 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'public/empty.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 00:00:05.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17 kb/s
  Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1024x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 7 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Filter concat:out:a0 has an unconnected output
```

Comment: Show the **complete** log.

Comment: @llogan i've added it

Comment: The log appears not to match the command you showed in the question (due to `Trailing option(s) found in the command: may be ignored`).

Comment: I have a version of this same command, with the options in the same order, just with 1 more video spliced in, and it runs successfully. Additionally the command in my post was pasted directly from my code file. The only option is `-vsync 2 `, right?  Even removing that i still get the warning about trailing options.

Comment: Are you executing ffmpeg directly from a command-line interface, or is it part of a script/code? How can we duplicate this issue? Because I am unable to.

Comment: No this is executed inside a Rails application. Running it from the command line did work, so it seems the issue must be from the environment I'm running the command in. Thanks for guiding me to this realization.

Comment: Show your code and add the [tag:ruby-on-rails] tag.